# How can I pass list of complex objects to webapi from breezejs?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, breeze

I found that using [fromapi] attribute I can pass one complex object.
when I try to pass list of complex objects it doesn't work.

in the client side I use breeze. server side is webapi.

How can I do this?

Comment: I think that its already in json format

http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/entity-serialization.html

And I asked for list of complex objects and not only one

Answer (score 0):

You can create one DTO which has property for your list of objects

```
public class CreateUserDto
{
   public string Name {set;get;}
   public List<RoleDto> Roles {set;get;}
   public CreateUserDto()
   {
      this.Roles = new List<RoleDto>();
   }
}
public class RoleDto
{
  public int Id {set;get;}
  public string Name {set;get;}
}
```

And you can use that as the argument of your Web api endpoint

```
public HttpResponseMesssage Save(CreateUserDto model)
{
  //Check model.Roles now
  // to do  : Return a response
}
```

From client, you can send data like this.(Assuming you have jQuery library loaded to your page)

```
var data { Name : "TestName",Roles:[]}
data.Roles.push(new { Id:1,Name:"Admin"});
data.Roles.push(new { Id:2,Name:"Editor"});

$.post("YourEndpointHere",data,function(response){
  // do something with response
});
```

Modelbinding will take care of converting the posted form data to an instance of CreateUserDto in your Save method. You can access `model.Roles` property to get the list of complex objects you wanted.

Comment: the objects are from c# EF and I prefer not to create new classes and use the default one that was created from EF. Is their any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Dictionary as below:

```
[HttpPost]
public IQueryable<Product> GetProducts(Dictionary<string, object> data)
{
    var categoryId = Convert.ToInt32(data["categoryId"]);
    var category = _context.Categories.Single(a => a.ID == categoryId);

    var galleryId = Convert.ToInt32(data["galleryId"]);

    var langId = Convert.ToInt32(data["langId"]);

    var searchStr = data["str"];

    return category.Products.Where(a => a.GalleryID == galleryId, a.LanguageID == langId, a.Description.Contains(searchStr))

}
```

Comment: I want to pass the objects as they are and not the ids